# Why are const Widgets in Dart not identical?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, constants

When we call `identical()` on two widgets created using their `const` constructors, it return false. Whereas while calling the same for two non widget objects it returns `true`.

Why is that ?

```
void main() {

  final a = const Center(
    child: const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),)
  );

  final b = const Center(
    child: const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),)
  );

  assert(identical(a, b)); // false


  var a1 = const EdgeInsets.all(8);

  var b1 = const EdgeInsets.all(8);


  assert(identical(a1, b1)); // true

}
```

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:todo_improve/main.dart': Failed assertion: line 17 pos 8: 'identical(a, b)': is not true.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry. Can you please check again. Disable 2 line : var a = const EdgeInsets.all(8);  var b = const EdgeInsets.all(8);

Comment: Nothing's changed in your code. I'm unable to reproduce. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Here is the error: https://imgur.com/a/PdRSbpZ. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

After much research, this is what I found out.

Now one main difference between your first and second cases is that a and b are `Widget`s in first case while in second case they are not.

Now, flutter has a `--track-widget-creation` flag which is enabled by default in debug modes.

This is the main culprit which makes your seemingly `const` widgets as non `identical`.

Now this means that when you run your app in release mode, your widgets will indeed be `compile time constants` and thus the `identical` function would indeed return true.

Change your code to (changing because assert calls are ignored in release mode)

```
final a =  const Center(
  child: const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),)
);

final b = const Center(
  child: const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),)
);

print(identical(a, b));
```

Then try running your code in `release` mode using `flutter run --release` and check your console to see that `true` will be printed. If you run in debug using `flutter run`, you will see `false` in the console.

Refer to this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44858) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much.!!! I don't know there is such a thing.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Do consider accepting the answer so that it may help others with the same question. :)